# Why does 500 % 30 return 20 in Swift

Tags: modulo

I'm currently trying to learn Swift for iOS app development. I'm fairly new to programming in general but do have some experience in other languages

I've just learnt about the modulo operator, or the remainder operator depending on what you call it. (%)
It should return the remainder of an equation, right?

```
var equation = 500 % 30
```

When I print equation, it writes '20' but I can't figure out why? 30 does not fit into 500 20 times, it's 16.6. The / operator would return 16 so I expected % to return whatever the remainder is?

Please tell me if I'm being stupid but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a % b` does not determine how many times `b` fits into `a`. The modulo operator determines what remains when you subtract the largest multiple of `b` that is smaller than `a` from `a`. In this case, the largest multiple of `30` that is smaller than `500` is `480`, and `500 - 480 = 20`, so `500 % 30 = 20`.

Answer (score 2):

I feel stupid. Sorry.

480 is the highest number 30 can perfectly fit into, which leaves 20 remaining.